# 2D Moving Camera (LWJGL)

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I'm currently developing a 2D RPG with LWJGL, and am still in the engine stage of development. I've got a lot of the tech I want created, but one of my big problems is fixing the camera on the player. All the solutions I've seen involve moving the world and keeping the player still, which can work, but it seems apparent that this can cause some calculation issues if not closely monitored. Normally, I'd write a system where I wouldn't have to worry about it, but I refuse, because I eventually intend on adding multiplayer capability, where a moving world would be unplayable.

Is there a way to affix the camera to an object or point that can move WITHOUT using translate to move the world around? Also, I'd like to avoid Slick if possible. That would require me to rework much of my game engine as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are going to project the 3d viewport onto a 2d screen you need to move everything according to the point of view of the observer (the so called camera or view).

I guess you can't escape from this. What you usually do is having a `Camera` object which holds position and rotation that is used to build the view matrix which is passed to the vertices of your scene through a `uniform` to the shaders. Passing transformation matrices to shaders is the normality so you shouldn't feel burdened by it. You can always premultiply it with the perspective matrix.

You must move the whole world to match the position of your camera just because you need to transform everything in your scene as it is seen from that point of view, otherwise how could you then project it on your screen? There is no "move the camera, keep the world still" concept.

Comment: Two concerns: One, this is a 2d project, so I don't know how much of your 3d knowledge applies. Two, if the world moves, how on Earth does multiplayer work if every player moves the world around them rather than moving themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Move the world *visually*, it's how every other RPG does it. Don't move the actual world's location though.

Draw everything but the ui normally, than translate it all according to the players position (i.e. `glTranslate2f(-player.x,-player.y)`). This is all done in the render method. On networked multiplayer, the viewport is done to that specific player (i.e. Bob's screen is translated based off Bob's position, Jane's is translated based off Jane's position). Should you instead want single-screen multiplayer, you will probably have to use mutliple framebuffers (one per player), and use them as viewports.

Comment: I added `glTranslatef(-game.player.getX(),-game.player.getY(),0);` to my main render method just before `Display.update();`, but I get no results. The player's position is held in those methods.

Comment: glTranslatef should be called before you render the player, not after. You should push a transformation matrix, glTranslatef(...), draw the world and enemies and characters, pop the transformation matrix, draw the UI, then call Display.update(), in that exact order.